# An issue with DataTables - sScrollX property not working

Tags: datatable, datatables

My JavaScript looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#ecTable').dataTable({
            "sScrollY": "580px",
            "sScrollX": "600px",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
        });
    });
```

And the resulting table looks as follows:
[image]

As you can see, something isn't right. I can't seem to get DataTables to actually display the X scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
"sScrollXInner": "100%",
"sScrollX": "100%"
```